# Why doesn't Espresso wait for actual view conditions?

Tags: java, android, android-testing, android-espresso

Why doesn't `Google Espresso` actually wait for `View` conditions to become `true` and instead only checks `IdlingResources` and `AsyncTaks` to become idle and assert s the conditions? It would be so much easier and more reliable if instead of waiting for the latter `Espresso` would just continue checking until after the View conditions fulfil.

For example, currently `onView(withId(R.id.someView)).check(matches(<some conditions>))` may fail because at a time when `IdlingResources` and `AsyncTaks` are idle the `View` is not there yet and so the check may immediately fail.

I know I could create an `IdlingResource` to wait for my `View` conditions but again, why to do this if it could be easily done by default...